# How do they publish 50mb+ apk

Tags: android, apk, publish, multiple-apk

I have seen google apk expansion files guide (about 2GB main and 2GB patch).
However many apps are not using this stuff. There is no downloading started after application 1st run, and at the same moment this applications are larger than 50mb. 
For example this one (greater than 50mb):
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.minoraxis.roc.google

Here is an even 255mb size app that is also downloading nothing after install: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kabam.ff6android.

Do I need to have some special google account or build a some kind of multiple apk to get possible to put extra 100megabytes of data into my application? Some users are quite dissapointed when after application is finally loaded and installed it starts to download something again...

Comment: Expansion files are normally downloaded during the installation process. This is indistinguishable for a user from a single apk install. A separate download at app start is the exception.

Comment: I am confused a bit. How's that? I cant believe my device indistinguishably have downloaded 200mb in just a few seconds. Or do you mean that this extensions are included in application download process. What is this all about then?
http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: Please help me someone I am still confused...

Comment: Read the section "Download Process" in the link you have just posted: Most of the time, Google Play downloads and saves your expansion files at the same time it downloads the APK to the device.

Comment: That really works as you say, thank you!